# Zend Framework Class Displaying Code

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework application running on a local web server.  I've run into an issue where it displays the code for certain classes.  It looks like the autoloader isn't working.  Whenever it tries to use a class that should have been autoloaded, it crashes saying it can't find the class, and prints the contents of the php file containing the class it was looking for.

Here's my autoloader

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    echo "in autoload";
    // Set up autoload.
    $obj_loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $obj_loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);


    $obj_loader->registerNamespace('Gutterbling_'); 

    return $obj_loader;
}
```

The class that can't be found is Gutterbling_Acl.  It doesn't say the file can't be found, just the class.

Comment: Do you have the full error message? Sorry but I've seen too many people make the wrong assumption/conclusion when interpreting error messages. I'd rather see it with my own eyes than rely on *"...crashes saying it can't find the class, and prints the contents of the php file..."*

Comment: ** The full text from the file Gutterbling/Acl.php ** Fatal error: Class 'Gutterbling_Acl' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/local.hacksnitch.com/app/application/modules/user/Bootstrap.php on line 243

Comment: If I comment out the code that uses that Acl class, it will crash trying to load something else and print that whole file followed by a similar error.

Comment: The autoloader works fine on a different site on an external server.  I haven't seen this problem until I started running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Warning : dirty quick answer.

A look in one of my Zend app and I've seen this line just before the return statement (and I don't have the call to setFallbackAutoloader) :

```
$obj_loader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
  'namespace' => '',
  'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
```

Add it and test.

Comment: Same error.  If I try to register the namespace I get an error saying that's not supported with this class.  So I'm starting to think my namespace isn't being registered in the first place.

Comment: Actually just dumped my autoloader with the method above.  Looks like the namespace is there there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Sorry to waste everyone's time.  The problem was, the remote server has php short tags enabled.  The local server does not.  The files that aren't working start with

Again, sorry about that.  Hopefully this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: You might delete your question if it's irrelevant then